# Bittorrent using only 5 connections

Tags: speed, connection, bittorrent

I'm downloading a torrent with over 350 seeders and 2200 leechers. However I only download at about 10 kbps with 5 seeds/leechers.

I'm figuring out it's because utorrent didn't check for speed with other users. How can I force that so that utorrent uses the fastest seeds around?

Also, availability is 8.999 which is weird, shouldn't that be around 350 ?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the trackers, if any one is not connecting (ex. link not available), delete it. It helps to increase the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the number of connections you have set in the preferences?

1. Open uTorrent.
2. Click Options and select Preferences
3. Check the Number of Connections

As you can see from the below screenshot I have a maximum number of 500 connections and share it by limiting each torrent to a maximum of 250 connections each.

[image]

Comment: Yes good suggestion but I already have this